# How to search string between two specific strings and print string1 line, matched string line and the single followed line after match (duplicated)

Tags: awk, sed, command

I have a file;

I want to print the line 'xref id=....' only if it is followed by string 'desc="Transcription' before executing another string 'xref id=' for next match.
So in the output, I want to print (1) xref id=... line (2) signature ac... line and (3) one more line present just after signature ac... line.

Input file:

xref id= A7877

abc .....

xyz ....

xref id= B7867

yxc .....

signature ac="PF123" desc="Transcription

gtx ...

vtx ...

xref id= F7866

xcvv ..

dfg .....

signature ac="PF724" desc="Transcription

abx....

tuv .....

Xref id= V7846

asc ...

tyc ...

Output:

xref id= B7867

signature ac="PF123" desc="Transcription

gtx ...

xref id= F7866

signature ac="PF724" desc="Transcription

abx....

Answer (score 0):

A solution in `sed`:

```
sed -n -e '/^xref id=/{h; d;}' -e '/desc="Transcription/{$!N; H; g; p;}' file
```

And in `awk`

```
awk '
    desc != ""            { print xref ORS desc ORS $0; desc = ""; next }
    /^xref id=/           { xref = $0; next }
    /desc="Transcription/ { desc = $0 }
    END                   { if (desc != "") print xref ORS desc }
' file
```

Note that both ignore the line matching `^xref id=` if it immediately follows the line containing `desc="Transcription`.

Comment: @ Aydin: It needs little modification and is not working properly. I just need to begin the search with the string 'xref id=' and if there is 'desc="Transcription' in any line before the next 'xref id=' search, then print both lines (+1 line after 'desc="Transcription' ). If it didn't find 'desc="Transcription'  before next 'xref id=', then ignore the xref line...

Comment: @Annotator It gives the same output as the expected output given, for the input sample given in the question. You may consider modifying the sample input and expected output to reflect those conditions.

Comment: @Aydin: One option might be just to look for string 'desc="Transcription' and print the following 1 line using the -A 1 flag. But I don't know which flag to use for its first preceding line that contain xref id= (not all preceding xref id=) and print it with other two lines.

Comment: @Aydin: it is not giving the 'xref id=' line in the output which is important because it will reflect which xref id contain Transcription.

Comment: @Annotator It is giving the `xref id=` line in my tests. I suspect the format of real data is different from the sample data given in the question.

Comment: @Aydin: I was just looking the original file and I noticed that it contains multiple 'xref' (for example go-xref etc) between 'xref id='  and 'desc="Transcription section' section and even after  'desc="Transcription section' there are some xref present. but 'xref id=' are unique. may be 'xref' is causing the error.

Comment: @Aydin: Also, is it possible to remove the condition 'Note that both ignore the line matching ^xref id= if it immediately follows the line containing desc="Transcription' ...